# limit of $x(t)$ given its DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given that $x(t)$ is a nonconstant solution to $x' = x^2 - 3x - 4$, which of the following are possibilities for the limit of $x(t)$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$?

Letting $x'=0$, I see that the critical points are at $x=-1$ and $x=4$. 
Drawing a phase line, it is stable at $x=-1$ and unstable at $x=4$.
Hence as $t\rightarrow\infty$, $x$ may go to $\infty$ (if it's above 4) or converge towards $x=-1$. Is this way of thinking right?

Comment: It seems to be ok. What is the potential problem you think of?